# Why does this Show instance in Haskell (Hugs) cause a stack overflow error?

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, polymorphism, hugs

The following is a polymorphic data type in Haskell, interpreted by Hugs. I am trying to create an instance of Show for Equality.

The instance declaration says that if a type "a" is in Show, then Equality a is in Show. It should print the two arguments to the constructor Equals a b in the form "a = b".

```
data Equality a = Equals a a 

instance (Show a) => Show (Equality a) where
show (Equals a b) = a ++ " = " ++ b
```

Yet, typing something into Hugs like "(Equality 9 9)" yields:

ERROR - C stack overflow

So, I tried indenting the "show (Equals a b)..." line with a couple of spaces. I'm not sure what the difference would be, but was just playing around and then got this:

```
Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : show
*** Expected type : Show (Equality a) => Equality a -> String
*** Inferred type : Show (Equality [Char]) => Equality [Char] -> String
```

Can anyone explain why these errors are occurring, or suggest a better way of implementing this show instance?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a bad idea in general: `Show` is meant to provide a basic serialisation mechanism for Haskell, producing valid Haskell code (modulo import details).  If you want to do custom output formatting, then produce a custom `prettyPrint :: a -> String` function or similar, possibly using a pretty-printing library for complex outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indenting does matter due to Haskell's at-times-strange whitespace sensitivity. Without the indent, the compiler cannot tell that the following statement belongs to the `where`.

The error that you are getting is because the polymorphic type, having no constraints, does not ensure that `a` and `b` can concatenated with the " = " string. What if you have `Equals 1 1`. How would you concatenate that without making the Ints strings first?

However, if you `show` a and b first, all works out because `show` martials the values into something that can be concatenated with a String.

```
data Equality a = Equals a a

instance (Show a) => Show (Equality a) where
    show (Equals a b) = (show a) ++ " = " ++ (show b)
```

Comment: Ah. I danced around that for a while but couldn't put it all together. Thank you for the clear, detailed, and exampled response.

Comment: You can safely eliminate the parens around `(show a)` and `(show b)`

Comment: I wouldn't say that the indentation rules are strange... if this line belongs to something, indent it more!

Comment: I guess I mean that they are "at first blush" strange. Ha. It took me a few days to feel completely comfortable with when I had to indent, when I had to indent past an equal sign etc. But by this measure (that of my slow grokking) much of Haskell is strange. But good strange!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is indented incorrectly. It defines an empty `Show` instance:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Equality a) where
```

and a separate top-level function `show`:

```
show (Equals a b) = a ++ " = " ++ b
```

of type `Equality [Char] -> [Char]`. So when you try to use your `Show` instance, the [default definition of `show` from the `Show` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Show.html#Show) gets picked up. Looking at the code:

```
showsPrec _ x s = show x ++ s
show x          = showsPrec zeroInt x ""
```

you can see that the default `show` is defined in terms of `showsPrec`, which is in turn defined in terms of `show`. This explains why your program goes into an infinite loop.

To fix the code, indent it appropriately, and add missing calls to `show` to fix the type error (which stems from the fact that you can't concatenate an arbitrary type `a` with a string - you have to convert `a` to a string first):

```
data Equality a = Equals a a

instance (Show a) => Show (Equality a) where
  show (Equals a b) = show a ++ " = " ++ show b
```

Testing:

```
*Main> show (Equals 9 9)
"9 = 9"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you didn't call function `show` on arguments `a` and `b`. I did this in GHC but I think it should work:

```
data Equality a = Equals a a 

instance (Show a) => Show (Equality a) where
  show (Equals a b) = show a ++ " = " ++ show b
```

Then:

```
> Equals 9 9
9 = 9
```