# Infinite loop when trying to define instance Show for a datatype

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a installed module with data type Card. I make it instance of class Show but something go wrong in the ghci:

```
 module Poker where

 data Card = Card Int 

 ...

 instance Show Card where
 show card = ...

 ...
```

I open the ghci and type:

```
>:m + Poker
>Card 0
..
..
..
(Nothing) => I stop the execution
>Poker.show (Card 0)
> "Ace of Hearts"
```

It seem that my data type is not an instance of the class Show, why?

---

Thanks all! It works! :)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863176/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Indentation matters.** The body of an instance declaration needs to be indented, otherwise it interprets your definition of `show` as just another top-level function, which is why `Poker.show` works.

```
instance Show Card where
    show card = ...
```

The general indentation rule in Haskell is that if two consecutive lines are indented the same, they are two distinct definitions, whereas if a line is more indented than the one before it, it is considered to be part of the preceding definition or expression, which is what you want in this case.

The reason why this causes an infinite loop, is that since you didn't provide an implementation of `show` in the type class, it uses the default implementation which indirectly calls `showsPrec`. Since you didn't provide that one either, it uses the default implementation which calls `show`. Thus, you get an infinite loop. Several type classes have default implementations implemented in terms of each other like that, so that you only have to implement a subset of them.

Comment: My impression, from this and the other question he posed, is that indentation rule that has gone awry here is the markdown indentation rule. Something else is mysterious here though.

Comment: @applicative: Perhaps, but this is consistent with the behavior the OP is experiencing. If `show` was not properly indented, `Poker.show` would work, while `Prelude.show` would diverge. So unless the OP states otherwise, I think it's reasonable to assume that this is the problem.

Comment: No, at least I can't get that result; ghci just declares the imaginary new 'show' to be ambiguous and refuses to interpret the file. It doesn't matter if I add the defective `Show` instance while the module in question is in scope but then reload after adding those lines.

Comment: @applicative: I can reproduce it perfectly. There is nothing ambiguous about _defining_ a function whose name shadows one from the Prelude. Referring to it just as `show` would indeed be ambiguous, but that's not what the OP is doing. In the first case, GHCi is hardwired to use `Prelude.show`, and in the second case the OP is using the fully qualified name `Poker.show`, which is not ambiguous.

Comment: @applicative: [Here](http://hpaste.org/54375) is the exact code I tested with. Load it in GHCi. `Card 0` diverges due to the implicit `Prelude.show`, while `Poker.show (Card 0)` prints `"woot"`. If you got ambiguity errors, I suspect you probably used `show` somewhere beyond just defining it.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now as I say above, indeed perfectly obvious; I was getting interference from a wrong move filling in the ellipsis on the right hand side of his `show card` -- using things involving Prelude.show, and thus wandered in the wrong direction. That `show card = show 3` isn't like `f x = f 3` is part of what was muddying things for me.